# Web Api 2 Login and Register Actions, JavaScript problems

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

Today I'm trying Web Api 2 Login and Register Actions. I'm using Standard Template from  Visual Studio 2015. I created JavaScript Client on  web  side, but I do not see alerts and registration is not working.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="email">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password" id="password">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password again" id="confirmpassword">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-info">
</div>
```

```
@section scripts{
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#submit').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var data = {
                Email: $('#email').val(),
                Password: $('#password').val(),
                ConfirmPassword: $('#confirmpassword').val()
            };

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/api/Account/Register',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: JSON.stringify(data)
            }).success(function (data) {
                alert("Registration  success");

            }).fail(function (data) {
                alert("Error message");
            });
        });
    })
</script>
}
```

**Update:** 
Here is code for login process:

```
div class="userInfo" style="display:none;">
<p>You are loged in as: <span class="userName"></span></p>
<input type="button" value="Log out" id="logOut" />
 </div>
 <div class="loginForm">
<h3>Log in</h3>
<label>Enter email</label><br />
<input type="email" id="emailLogin" /> <br /><br />
<label>Password</label><br />
<input type="password" id="passwordLogin" /><br /><br />
<input type="submit" id="submitLogin" value="Log in" />
</div>
@section scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    //...........................

    var tokenKey = "tokenInfo";
    $('#submitLogin').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var loginData = {
            grant_type: 'password',
            username: $('#emailLogin').val(),
            password: $('#passwordLogin').val()
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Token',
            data: loginData
        }).success(function (data) {
            $('.userName').text(data.userName);
            $('.userInfo').css('display', 'block');
            $('.loginForm').css('display', 'none');
            // store sessionStorage auth token
            sessionStorage.setItem(tokenKey, data.access_token);
            console.log(data.access_token);
        }).fail(function (data) {
            alert('Error on login');
        });
    });

    $('#logOut').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        sessionStorage.removeItem(tokenKey);
    });
})
</script>
}
```

**Update 2**
On registration here is F12 console code:

```
(index):88 Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax(...).success is not a function
at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> ((index):88)
at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.1.js:5201)
at HTMLInputElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.1.1.js:5009)
(anonymous) @ (index):88
dispatch @ jquery-3.1.1.js:5201
elemData.handle @ jquery-3.1.1.js:5009
```

But registration passes and I have new record in  database. Can anyone explain me what does it  mean?

Comment: Can you provide more info? Is the action being hit? If the action is being hit are the values coming correctly? Is there any error in browser development tools (F12)? Where is your action and viewmodel code? Regards.

Comment: @dime2lo, thanks for attention, no errors, registration passes successfully, there are  some problems with login I'll post login process now, login gives me 400 error, in  registration process .success(function (data) {
                alert("Registration  success"); not working, page des not show any information,  after click button I only see new user in  database.

Comment: @dime2lo thanks a lot I solved problem I've use done instead success.

Comment: @ArchilLabadze: I have rolled back your [solved] edit because we don't put answers in questions, and the solution was not very clear anyway. Would you post an answer in the answer box below? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

do it like this :

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/api/Account/Register',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  data: JSON.stringify(data)
  success: function(html){
    alert("Registration  success");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found that I've used submit type button, it's first misstake - if I want operate request using jquery I've use type="button" instead submit.
Another moment is that json properties is not difined in  right case:

```
var data = {
            email: $('#email').val(),
            password: $('#password').val(),
            confirmPassword: $('#confirmpassword').val()
        };
```

this will be correct

Now about error in console: correct is like @Mustapha answered

for example:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "/api/rooms",
success: function (rooms) { 

}
```

});

Here is fixed ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Token',
        data: loginData
        success: function(data) {
        $('.userName').text(data.userName);
        $('.userInfo').css('display', 'block');
        $('.loginForm').css('display', 'none');
        // store sessionStorage auth token
        sessionStorage.setItem(tokenKey, data.access_token);
        console.log(data.access_token);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert('Error on login');
    });
});
```

Here is, but I've done it using angular :)
Thanks.